# Cascade saving children objects in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms

Lets say I have an object called `Company` that is represented like so:

```
public class Company
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Line1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Line2 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Line3 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Town { get; set; }
    public virtual string County { get; set; }
    public virtual string Postcode { get; set; }
    public virtual double Longitude { get; set; }
    public virtual double Latitude { get; set; }
}
```

When I create a new company, I also want the new address to be created too. At the moment, I can only get this to work by creating the address record and then creating the company record separately:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(Company company)
    {
        _addressRepo.Create(company.Address);
        _companyRepo.Create(company);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

(Where _addressRepo and _companyRepo are of type `IRepository<Address>` and `IRepository<Company>` respectively)

How can I get all child objects to cascade save? So that ideally, when I call `_companyRepo.Create(company);`, Orchard handles all the child records for me?

I tried creating a new attribute so that properties can be marked as Cascade Save Update, but If I put a breakpoint on the Apply method it never appears to get hit.

```
public class CascadeSaveUpdateAttribute : Attribute {
}

public class CascadeSaveUpdateConvention :
    AttributeCollectionConvention<CascadeSaveUpdateAttribute>
{

    protected override void Apply(CascadeSaveUpdateAttribute attribute, ICollectionInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Cascade.SaveUpdate();
    }
}
```

What can I do to get this Cascade Save functionality working?